# How to make link in top navigation not clickable

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, navigation, top-link-bar

In my top navigation there are several links which are basically subsites. Under subsites are further sites or pages. I am using SharePoint 2013 default top navigation in my custom master page. I got its code from "Design Manager".

There is a particular top level subsite which I want to make unclickable. For e.g. currently this is the top navigation.

Home
Subsite1
Subsite2
Subsite3
Subsite4
Subsite5

I want to make Subsite1 unclickable so is there a way to put a # in its URL so when user clicks it, nothing happen.

Comment: That would confuse users, I'm sure. Why would you like to make a LINK not clickable? Isn't it better to hide it altogether? I'm just curious.

Comment: Because that link has no content but other links are coming under it have. This is client requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that using jQuery. Get the first link of the dropdown menu and set the href of that link.

```
$(function() {
    $("#DeltaTopNavigation > div > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:first").attr("href", "#");
});
```

If you want the link to be completely unclickable, then you could also remove its attribute.

```
$(function() {
    $("#DeltaTopNavigation > div > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > a:first").removeAttr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a `link` add a `label`

[image]

Comment: Your Answer fits for SharePoint Online/Modern Experience. The Question was for SharePoint 2013 which has no Modern Experience.

Comment: Sorry, I ended up here by searching for this also, so I thought others could end up here also

Comment: Welcome Ask a similar question relevant and then answer it yourself, that way it can benefit others without adding confusion original question